# Get value of an input box using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the text in an input box,

```
<input type="text" name="inputbox" value="name" class="box">
```

I started with

```
input = driver.find_element_by_name("inputbox")
```

I tried input.getText() but I got

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Comment: Please attach sample html. Thanks.

Comment: does the input really contain text? or you want to get/store value 'name' of the input's attribute 'value'? Because get_text usually gives you this kind of text: <div>some_text</div>

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use this to get the value of the input element:

```
input.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: For completeness: input.get_attribute('value').encode('utf-8')

Comment: while `input.text` does exist, it will not give you the value :(

Answer (score 25):

Note that there's an important difference between the value attribute and the value property.

The simplified explanation is that the value attribute is what's found in the HTML tag and the value property is what you see on the page.

Basically, the value attribute sets the element's initial value, while the value property contains the current value.

You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) and see an example of the difference [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cdq6m4xn/).

---

If you want the `value` **attribute**, then you should use get_attribute:

```
input.get_attribute('value')
```

If you want the `value` **property**, then you should use get_property

```
input.get_property("value")
```

---

Though, according to the docs, [get_attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) actually returns the property rather than the attribute, unless the property doesn't exist. [get_property](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_property) will always return the property.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the value of the input element:

```
text =driver.find_element('xpath',"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")
value = text.get_dom_attribute("value")
print(value)
```