# Can you copy the text of an input?

Tags: python, selenium, dom, copy

Is it possible to copy the text of an input?
If there was an input with "text" in it can you get selenium/python to copy it in your clipboard?

```html
<input type="text" style="cursor:text;background:none;" class="form-control input-sm" onmousemove="this.select()" value="This is a Text" readonly="">
```

Comment: Can you share more details about what exactly you want to do? Also add HTML of target `input` and your current code

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580569/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of an input box using Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580569/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just look for the HTML element you want to get the text from and do this :

```
my_text = input_element.get_attribute('value')
```