# get content produced by Html button in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, quora

Using Selenium I am trying to read the content of an href link contained in "a" tag, which is  "View Upvoter" button on Quora (give you upvoters username list) , i am using this python code in selenium but the result i get is always is empty, any suggestions?
Here is the python code:

```
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_class_name("VoterListModalLink")
inputElement.send_keys("\n") #send enter for links, bttons
print(inputElement.text)
```

Here is the quora button html :

```
 <a class="AnswerVoterListModalLink VoterListModalLink"
   href="/api /mobile_expanded_voter_list?key=zDDQQihxghH&amp;type=answer" 
   id="__w2_iXtwcOw_modal_link" target="_blank">View Upvoters
 </ a>
```

link to site :https://www.quora.com/Can-you-cash-out-bitcoins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 **View Upvoters** link in the link which you have shared with us.

For retrieving href attribute from DOM, you can first store 5 web elements in a list , then use a for each loop to extract the required attribute.

**code** :

```
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/Can-you-cash-out-bitcoins")

upvoter_list = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('View Upvoters')
print(len(upvoter_list))

for voter in upvoter_list:
  print(voter.get_attribute('href'))
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/Can-you-cash-out-bitcoins")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  

upvoter_list = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('View Upvoters')
print(len(upvoter_list))

#Clicking on first upvoter list
upvoter_list[0].click()

time.sleep(10)

#Now we will get all the names from newly opened pop up 
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.modal_content.modal_body'))) 

upvoter_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.feed_item_answer_user'))) 

print(len(upvoter_name))
for names in upvoter_name:
 print(names.text)
```

Console output :

```
Jameson Williams
Fay M
David Robert
James Lathrom
James Newman
Debessence G
Valeriy Velchev
Chris Wright
BA Psychology, The University of Britis
Stanley Armando
Amisi Omomdi
Studies at The United States of America
Sathish Dilli Mohan
Just like you!
Alberto Guzman
Spanish-English Interpreter
Stephen C. Liu
Chief Matchmaker at M8 Relationship Mat
Ranieri Mestroni
Works at Parlanta Corp
Clasina Bos
Faryal Baloch
RheA Wolbrink
Krish Munot
Studied at Anna University, Tamil Nadu,
Heiko Yeh
Intern UX Design at Otto
David Jockers
Iddrisu Sadik Debabs
Works at Debabs Inc
Arkadiusz Hukalowicz
Joel Dubow
Sanjeev Kumar
Self Employed at Share Market India (19
Sandy
Wilfred Lee
Works at Investment Banking
Peter Yeung
Michael Donahue
SYED JALAL
Joshua Stockton
Works at University of Phoenix
Max Gauth
Dejan Cvetkovic
Joseph "Alec" Sidwa
Worked at Eastman Kodak Products and Se
Stavros Asimakopoulos
Vijay Paramasivam Rajasekaran
Studied at Jayaram College of Engineeri
Bitoshi Sakamoto
Girish Illindram
Engineer at Kuwait Oil Company (2016-pr
Faliq Nordin
Yamil Munoz
Worked at Odebrecht
Wesley Knope
I own some
Vinay Kumar
Works at Sonata Software
Jack Vi
Tony Aidinis
Project Manager at CryptoRose Analytics
Renee Bahman
Apoorv Jain
Bitcoin and alt coins trading.
Ashton Simonek
Studies Investing & Business at Self-Te
Chris Kelly
Cathy Young Brown
LDS, Married 42 years, Mom of 5 & Nana
Jonas Grandt
Jun Rong Tan
Seth Benton
M.S. from Arizona State University (200
José Romero
Worked at Universidad Nacional Abierta
Marijn Edens
Studied at KU Leuven
Mehmet Bal
Software Engineer
Stan Marian
Alan Morrison
Sr. Research Fellow at PricewaterhouseC
Jay Jackson
Jacob Hood
Assembly Line Worker at Honda Of Canada
Dawei Chen
Worked at University of Southern Califo
Jeffrey Tyson
Elliott Wells
Former Real Estate Investor
Sid Maher
Director at Casiki Media Ltd (2017-pres
Adithya G Kamath
Pritam Garud
Works at Tata Motors
Bence Mitlasóczki
M.Sc Physics, University of Bonn (2019)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This gives me an href link indeed, but i am looking for the html content of href, not the href itslelf.  Plus when i try to open the resulted href manually it does give me :'Page not found' error, This is the href i am trying to open:https://www.quora.com/api/mobile_expanded_voter_list?key=2EacbahnSx&type=answer

Comment: Meaning you want to extract the value of href attribute from DOM ?

Comment: if you mean by the value of href : the names of the upvoters in this case, then yes!

Comment: any suggestions @cruisepandey ?

Comment: When I click on view upvoter then a pop up appear with the name of all up voters. I am not sure that you are looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Youcef :Updated the whole code under update 1 with console output.

Comment: note that i replaced the line : upvoter_list[0].click()  with : clickEvent =ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(upvoter_list[0]).click().perform()

Comment: No problem , Would you mind accepting this as an answer , if that worked for you? In case you want to accept it, simply click on check mark which is just under the down vote button. Or in case you want to go through accepted answer , then you can follow : (stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Get value of an input box using Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580569/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python) :

```
inputElement.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: did not work for me, when i use this code i get "None" as result, what i want to get is content of the box, which is the upvoters names