# How to check if the text field conains inputed per defined text in Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, testing, assert

I tried to use some assert statements but it everytime fails.

```
button_test1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="custom-select"]')[0]
button_test1.click()

time.sleep(2)

button_test2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Box Sport Žilina")]')[0]
button_test2.click()

time.sleep(2)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Box Sport Žilina")]').text

time.sleep(2)

assert element == "Box Sport Žilina"
```

Comment: What does it show, if you `print(element)`?

Comment: Post your relevant HTML for better response from contributor.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` in the `xpath` means you will get a partial match

```
<div>Box Sport Žilina some more text<div>
```

Or even with a blank space

```
<div> Box Sport Žilina<div> <!-- the text is equal to ' Box Sport Žilina' -->
```

Will match, and `element` will have this text, which is not equals to `'Box Sport Žilina'`. Check contains in the assertion as well

```
assert 'Box Sport Žilina' in element
```

Comment: so i need some other method instead contains?

Comment: @LukeTeensie Contains is fine, but if you want to assert exact match you should check it's really an exact match, without blank spaces or unicode characters.

Comment: @LukeTeensie Because `"box"` is not equal to `"Box Sport Žilina"` either.

Comment: @LukeTeensie if this is only white spaces issue you can do `assert element.strip() == "Box Sport Žilina"`

Answer (score 0):

Try with input.get_attribute('value')

Refer URL: [Get value of an input box using Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580569/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python)

Comment: I tried but it do not works. Value means the text I write into field? First thing that I have some dropdown list and pre-defined text in code, it works with assert for only string without spaces. Second thing is when I imput some text I write myself. It is not saved to code or its not visible "there"...